# How to create chart from mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, charts

i have this table in mysql :
[this is my mysql table to make you better understand the use case and why i still did not find answer on the web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76KcG.png)

***how can i create three separate chart using the table. In this case, it will be three chart which is male chart, female chart and other chart. in each chart i want to show how much male select orange, how much select apple, banana and grape. same goes to other chart***.

my search always brought me to something that being preset with value to create the chart, which i think it is straightforward. Does anyone know how to do this? your help is appreciated.

p/s: i already read those question that already being asked as what i said most of them are preset value.

Comment: Please put your schema into the question rather than using a linked image which may in due course become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question to general, here is the steps you need to do

1. include chart library file such as fusion chart libraries
2. make sure you're connected to your mysql database
3. write a query and return it as json data
4. create chart container to render it in html page
5. you are done

Comment: how can i calculate how much orange that gender=male has selected?

Comment: and how can i do this in PHP (or is it JS only solution?)
.
any link to a tutorial is appreciated sir.

Comment: hi, you can google with keyword *fusion charts php mysql* or this https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/using-with-server-side-languages/tutorials/php-mysql-charts hope this helps

Comment: nice . but i have read it before this. just different than my use case ~ i think. that's the reason i came to stackoverflow and ask. i want to create something like male chart and it will show graph how many male choose orange, how many choose apple, how many choose banana and how many choose grape. so if there is any other male came and choose orange, total of male choose orange will add up and change the chart. the data is from this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/76KcG.png .  . anyway, thanks for the generous guide sir.

Comment: to create male or female chart, isn't that depends on your query?create a variable to store your male or female number from database and visualize it to your view page